# Why won't showSoftInput display the virtual keyboard?

Tags: java, android, virtual-keyboard

Essentially I am trying to show the virtual keyboard and gather input without the use of a visible `EditText` or `TextView`.  I realize that `toggleSoftInput` can be used to do this however I need to use `showSoftInput` because I want to use a `TextWatcher` for manipulating the input.  Also, the engine I am using is c++ so I am trying to do as little java-only code as possible so I am avoiding the .xml files.  So here goes...

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    protected GameView view = null;
    protected EditText editText;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        view = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(view);

        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setCursorVisible(false);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }

    public boolean showKeyboard()
    {
        JniApp.log("showKeyboard() in Java invoked!!!");

        editText.requestFocus();
        editText.requestFocusFromTouch();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
```

Where `showKeyboard()` is my c++ call into java.  I have checked to make sure that `editText` is receiving focus and it is.  However, `showSoftInput` returns false.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: After some debugging it looks as if `requestFocus` returns true but the activity still says `view` is the current focus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it with .SHOW_IMPLICIT instead of .SHOW_FORCED ?

Have you tried it on other emulators / devices with maybe other Android versions?